# Cross Origin Resource Sharing error while making put request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, cors

I got this error while making put request.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:5000/api/products/undefined' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is
>   not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

I have even included CORS policy in main server file

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that the parameter you send request to is **"undefined"** ?
*("'http://localhost:5000/api/products/undefined'")*

If the problem is caused by cors error, you can try this:
install [cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to your nodejs server

```
npm install cors
```

then put this line to your server file:

```
....
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
....
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the header function should receive only two parameters at a time:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
    next();
});
```

For more details on how to enable CORS on ExpressJS see this reference:
https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

You can use a npm package, this package is a middleware, to install it just do:

```
npm install cors
```

And to use it:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

For details on how to use the cors package refers to this documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html